# Why does folder redirection remain even after removing roaming profile and redirection settings?

Tags: windows

So, I create a share. I create a folder called profiles. I set user profile path in AD to said share for two users: `user1` and `user2` in this case. I log on to a machine using `user1` account. When I log in with the first account, I see on the Desktop 2 folders: `user1.V2` and `user2.V2` which is not what I wanted.

Users have their AD profile path as:

```
\server\Users\profiles\user1
for user 1

\server\Users\profiles\user2
for user 2
```

So, I check folder redirects for `user1`, somehow a redirect got in there for desktop and was pointed to `\server\Users\profiles`. So, I revert that GP setting to Redirect to the local user profile location. I also remove this users' roaming profile location setting. Go back to machine, `gpupdate /force` and log back in as `user1`. The profile folders still seem to be the same.

```
Roaming profile: N/A
Folder redirection: N/A
```

Well, that's weird. Maybe it's cached and those folders are showing up accidentally. I'll try and delete them. It seems I can't I'll make a new folder... surely it won't show up... It seems to still be on the server in the roaming profile folder, which isn't set and in the redirected desktop location isn't set either...

It seems strange these days to expect that changing a setting on a Windows machine would have any effect at all. That is until one of those mystery-reboot-something-changed-happenstances.

So, why would my folders still be redirecting if both `gpresult` and `rsop` show nothing hinting at folder redirection nor roaming profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder redirection group policy settings have an option for whether to remove the redirection or not in the event that the group policy setting is later removed or no long applicable.  I believe the default is for the redirection to remain in place.

Double-check that the group policy setting is set to "redirect to the local userprofile location" rather than "not configured".  I would expect gpresult to show this setting, not to say N/A.

Roaming profiles are kept synchronized with the local copies.  Removing the roaming profile setting will stop any future synchronization, but won't remove the local copy of the content.

Comment: I can't tell if it was the case as I had modified the GP settings already. But this seems likely to have been the issue. Thanks.